# Is clock interrupts and acknowledgement the same thing in TCP?

Tags: tcp

I learned that TCP uses acknowledgements to advance a data transmission between the sending and the receiving application.

Therefore, does acknowledgements function as clock interrupts to notify the sending application to continue sending more packages?

[image: This is image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TCP ACKs are network packets just like any other packet. What makes it an ACK is a particular bit in the TCP header. This bit only has any meaning to the networking protocol stack in the kernel. It means nothing to the NIC -- because the NIC doesn't understand or care about TCP. To the NIC, it's just another packet that it needs to send up to the system. This is accomplished via the normal mechanism the NIC uses to provide packets to the system.

Usually this works by placing the received packet into a DMA ring buffer, and then signalling an interrupt to notify the system that it should drain the buffer. But there is no requirement that it has to work this way and it depends on the particular NIC and host system; but unless you are writing kernel drivers, you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: So are clock interrupts what trigger more packets to be transferred from the
sender’s socket buffer to the NIC? And acknowledgements are used to trigger the clock interrupts?

Comment: No. The implementation of TCP is completely handled in the kernel. If the kernel's TCP stack is waiting for an ACK, and one arrives at the NIC, the NIC will send the packet up to the kernel (without understanding what it is, just that it's a packet with some bits in it), the kernel will interpret this as an ACK, do whatever bookkeeping it needs to do, and then send more packets back to the NIC for transmission if there's anything waiting in the kernel's socket write buffer and the TCP stack determines that it's appropriate to do so given the state of the connection.

Comment: so in summary, ACK and clock interrupts are two different things?

Comment: Absolutely, yes. An ACK is a TCP packet with the ACK bit set in the TCP header. It might help to understand what you're trying to do, or from what perspective you're trying to figure this stuff out. I'm also confused why you keep saying "clock interrupt." I don't know if you really understand what an _interrupt_ is, so I'm not sure what needs to be explained or in what way. Interrupts _are_ used in the implementation of most NIC peripheral interfaces to the kernel. But they're not _clock_ interrupts. And they are not necessary to understanding TCP or ACKs.